# JQ, Create New Dict With Two Unique Select Statements

Tags: jq

I have a response from the Graph API which contains an array of objects. Each object contains different evidence categories for an alert.

```bash
$ cat event.json | jq '.evidence[]."@odata.type"'                 
"#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence"
"#microsoft.graph.security.cloudApplicationEvidence"
"#microsoft.graph.security.cloudApplicationEvidence"
"#microsoft.graph.security.ipEvidence"
```

I am trying to construct a new object with the results, but the event structure is making this kind of difficult:

```json
{
  "id": "<redacted>",
  "providerAlertId": "<redacted>",
  "incidentId": "<redacted>",
  "status": "new",
  "severity": "low",
  "classification": null,
  "determination": null,
  "serviceSource": "microsoftDefenderForCloudApps",
  "detectionSource": "cloudAppSecurity",
  "detectorId": "MCAS_ALERT_ANUBIS_DETECTION_REPEATED_ACTIVITY_FAILED_LOGIN",
  "tenantId": "<redacted>",
  "title": "Multiple failed login attempts",
  "description": "The user <redacted> (<redacted>) performed more than 51 failed logins attempts in a single session.",
  "recommendedActions": "",
  "category": "CredentialAccess",
  "assignedTo": null,
  "alertWebUrl": "https://security.microsoft.com/alerts/<redacted>?tid=<redacted>",
  "incidentWebUrl": "https://security.microsoft.com/incidents/<redacted>?tid=6<redacted>",
  "actorDisplayName": null,
  "threatDisplayName": null,
  "threatFamilyName": null,
  "mitreTechniques": [
    "T1110",
    "T1110.001"
  ],
  "createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:13:38.812686Z",
  "lastUpdateDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:14:46.6766667Z",
  "resolvedDateTime": null,
  "firstActivityDateTime": "2023-03-01T17:56:52.145Z",
  "lastActivityDateTime": "2023-03-01T17:58:11.708Z",
  "comments": [],
  "evidence": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence",
      "createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:13:38.8966667Z",
      "verdict": "unknown",
      "remediationStatus": "none",
      "remediationStatusDetails": null,
      "roles": [],
      "tags": [],
      "userAccount": {
        "accountName": "<redacted>",
        "domainName": null,
        "userSid": "<redacted>",
        "azureAdUserId": "<redacted>",
        "userPrincipalName": "<redacted>"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.cloudApplicationEvidence",
      "createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:13:38.8966667Z",
      "verdict": "unknown",
      "remediationStatus": "none",
      "remediationStatusDetails": null,
      "roles": [],
      "tags": [],
      "appId": 11161,
      "displayName": "Office 365",
      "instanceId": 0,
      "instanceName": null,
      "saasAppId": 11161
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.cloudApplicationEvidence",
      "createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:13:38.8966667Z",
      "verdict": "unknown",
      "remediationStatus": "none",
      "remediationStatusDetails": null,
      "roles": [],
      "tags": [],
      "appId": 28375,
      "displayName": "Microsoft Teams",
      "instanceId": 0,
      "instanceName": null,
      "saasAppId": 28375
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.security.ipEvidence",
      "createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T18:13:38.8966667Z",
      "verdict": "unknown",
      "remediationStatus": "none",
      "remediationStatusDetails": null,
      "roles": [
        "attacker"
      ],
      "tags": [],
      "ipAddress": "<redacted>",
      "countryLetterCode": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my first attempt:

```bash
➜  cat event.json | jq '[.evidence[] | {upn: .userAccount.userPrincipalName, ip: .ipAddress }]'
[
  {
    "upn": "<redacted>",
    "ip": null
  },
  {
    "upn": null,
    "ip": null
  },
  {
    "upn": null,
    "ip": null
  },
  {
    "upn": null,
    "ip": "<redacted>"
  }
]
```

This output makes sense. There are 4 objects contained within the `evidence[]` array. My next attempt was a proof of concept on simply selecting a specific object from the array, and it proved successful for a singular value:

```json
➜  cat event.json | jq '[.evidence[] | {upn: select(."@odata.type" == "#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence") | .userAccount.userPrincipalName, ip: .ipAddress }]'
[
  {
    "upn": "<redacted>",
    "ip": null
  }
]
```

Obviously, the select `userEvidence` object doesn't contain an IP - no surprise that field returned `null`. I figured I could simply do another select statement to get the IP, but this causes a complete whiff:

```bash
➜  cat event.json | jq '[.evidence[] | {upn: select(."@odata.type" == "#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence") | .userAccount.userPrincipalName, ip: select(."@odata.type" == "#microsoft.graph.security.ipEvidence") | .ipAddress }]'
[]
```

How might I accomplish this? Why are my current attempts unsuccessful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.evidence[] | …`, you first iterate over the array, and just then produce whatever you produce but once for each array item. IIUC, you want one object (per `.evidence` array, probably), and collect various parts from single array items into it. Therefore, you need to iterate for each of those parts separately in order to retrieve the matching ones: `.evidence | … [] … [] …`.

```bash
.evidence | {
  upn: (.[] | select(."@odata.type" == "#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence").userAccount.userPrincipalName),
  ip: (.[] | select(."@odata.type" == "#microsoft.graph.security.ipEvidence").ipAddress)
}
```

```json
{
  "upn": "<redacted>",
  "ip": "<redacted>"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/p0tsj-iPQjh)

Be careful, though, because if any of the `(.[] | select(…) …)` constructs emits more than just one item, the whole output object will be duplicated, once for each one of them. You could thwart this by e.g. just taking the first match, as in `first(.[] | select(…) …)`.

Alternatively, if `."@odata.type"` is known to be unique across the array, all your constraints are based on it, and especially if there are many parts to collect, you might consider first building up an `INDEX` which you can use to reference the array items in constant time (instead of iterating through the array over and over again):

```bash
.evidence | INDEX(."@odata.type") as $e | {
  upn: $e["#microsoft.graph.security.userEvidence"].userAccount.userPrincipalName,
  ip: $e["#microsoft.graph.security.ipEvidence"].ipAddress
}
```

```json
{
  "upn": "<redacted>",
  "ip": "<redacted>"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yEvWJ_lptBz)